# C++ and xercesc: Cannot load message domain

Tags: c++, xerces, xerces-c

I'm trying to read a a XML file with C++ using xercesc. It compiles OK, but when I try to excecute the app (and read the XML), I get this error:

```
 Could not open catalog:
  XercesMessages_en_US.cat  or
  XercesMessages_en_US.cat
 Cannot load message domain
```

Someone knows what this means?

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself:

As the error says, xerces is unable to find XercesMessages_en_US.cat, wich is a file located in /usr/share/xerces-c/msg/ (in my case, gentoo linux).
To solve it, just need to write in a bash:
   export XERCESC_NLS_HOME=/usr/share/xerces-c/msg/
Then, it will find it.

In my case, I wrote this in .bashrc so it is exceuted in every start.